# Click search result link returned in a table

Tags: watir

I want to click on a link that is in a table. The links in the table are search results so will change depending on what you search for. I wish to click the first link in the table.

html is:

```
<div data-bind="visible: HasSearchResults">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'productSelectTemplate', foreach: SearchResults }">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <a href="#" class="autoResult" data-bind="text: id + '  (' + name + ')', click: function() { this.SelectProduct(); }">1724612110  (Nike item1)</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                 <a href="#" class="autoResult" data-bind="text: id + '  (' + name + ')', click: function() { this.SelectProduct(); }">5110000601  (Nike item2)</a>
                </td>                  
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                 <a href="#" class="autoResult" data-bind="text: id + '  (' + name + ')', click: function() { this.SelectProduct(); }">5110000602  (Nike item3)</a>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get elements by their index (with respect to the container being searched). Note that it is a zero-based index, so the first link would be index 0.

The following would click the first link in the table:

```
search_results_table = browser.table(:class => 'table table-bordered table-striped')
search_results_table.link(:index => 0).click
```

Note that the `:index => 0` is included in the locator by default, so you can actually omit it:

```
search_results_table.link.click
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your reply. I have tried the code you supplied but I am getting an error:                                                                                                         unable to locate element, using {:index=>0, :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)                                                                      I have also tried adding a sleep after the search to ensure that the the results are present to actually click

Comment: Are there multiple tables with the same class? What do you get if you do `puts browser.tables(:class => 'table table-bordered table-striped').length`?

Comment: yeah, think that may be the problem. When I tried the length code I get 6 returned. What can I do to identify the correct table?

Comment: You could locate the table by index - `browser.table(:index => 0)` and work the index value up until you get the right table. Or better, would be to see if there is a parent element to the div that is unique. Or even better, you could hope that the link class is unique and skip the table altogether - `browser.link(:class => 'autoResult').click`

Comment: yeah, there is a parent element called search results. So I have tried    link = @browser.div(:id, "searchResults")
  puts link.text
  link2 = link.table(:class, "table table-bordered table-striped")
  puts link2.text
  link2.link(:index => 0).click                                       However this is still not working. I get the error: unable to locate element, using {:index=>0, :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)                                   Any ideas?

Comment: When you do the `puts link2.text`, does the link you want to click get included in that text?

Comment: No, does not seem to. All I see in the console window is the error message. :-(

Comment: I am guessing a timing issue - ie it is asynchronously loading the search results? Try changing your last line to `link2.link(:index => 0).when_present.click`

Comment: SUCCESS!!! That worked perfectly! Thanks for all your help on this Justin, much obliged!